# Providing precise 12Vdc and 5A (approx) in a vehicle

Tags: dc-dc-converter, automotive, 12v, buck-boost

I need to have a relatively high amp (5A or close) source in a vehicle, as clean as possible, at a constant 12Vdc without big bumps or fluctuations. I know the regulator does the job by default, but just for keeping it safe I would like to have a device that takes the vehicle voltage and puts out 12Vdc flat.

I'm looking over eBay at buck-boost converters but for some reason not many of them are available with 4A.

Are there any devices you'd recommend in this case and also, a technical question: what are the downsides of using such a device, whether it be buck-boost or something else I'm not aware of; does it strain the vehicle power system in any way?

Comment: You can use an old surplus PC PSU with far better capacity and runs cool and very reliable, and oh yah , free ( just read how to use them with jumper)

Answer (score 1):

You can get a DC-to-DC converter (Like [this one](https://eu.mouser.com/ProductDetail/XP-Power/JCK5012S12?qs=w%2Fv1CP2dgqouNLoOdGyFaQ%3D%3D)) and hook it up to the DC Accessory port (make sure to check what the fuse value of that is, it is usually between 10 and 20 amps).

Comment: I've seen many similar devices like that on that site, similar wattage but some have elaborate cooling on them, and the one you posted looks very minimal, what are the differences between these then?